# Atomic Operation failed in CUDA

Tags: cuda

As the compute ability is 2.1, the `atomicAdd` and `atomicMax` operations do not support double precision, then I define both functions based on some answers on stack overflow.

It is strange that the `atomicAdd` function works well but the `atomicMax` doesn't work, here is my code.

The test of my code is to generate random number on each block, and then sum the random numbers on each block, we have block sum, I want to test the `atomicAdd` and `atomicMax` on the block sum.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curand.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define num_of_blocks 2
#define threads_per_block 2
#define tot_threads 4


__device__ double gsum[num_of_blocks];

__device__ double dev_sum;

__device__ double dev_max;

// set seed for random number generator
__global__ void initcuRand(curandState* globalState, unsigned long seed){
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    curand_init(seed, idx, 0, &globalState[idx]);
}

// atomiMax for double
__device__ double atomicMax_d(double* address, double val)
{
    unsigned long long int* address_as_i = (unsigned long long int*)address;
    unsigned long long int old = *address_as_i, assumed;
    do {
        assumed = old;
        old = ::atomicCAS(address_as_i, assumed, __double_as_longlong(::fmax(val, __longlong_as_double(assumed))));
    } while (assumed != old);
    return __longlong_as_double(old);
}

// atomicAdd for double
__device__ double atomicAdd_d(double* address, double val)
{
    unsigned long long int* address_as_ull = (unsigned long long int*)address;
    unsigned long long int old = *address_as_ull, assumed;
    do{
        assumed = old;
        old = atomicCAS(address_as_ull, assumed, __double_as_longlong(val + __longlong_as_double(assumed)));
    }while(assumed != old);
    return __longlong_as_double(old);
}

__global__ void kernel(curandState *globalState){
    // global id
    int gidx    = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    // local id
    int lidx    = threadIdx.x;

    // creat shared memory to store seeds
    __shared__ curandState localState[tot_threads];

    __shared__ double srandnum[threads_per_block];

    // copy global seed to local
    localState[lidx]    = globalState[gidx];

    //synchronize the local threads writing to the local memory cache
    __syncthreads();

    // generate random number from normal distribution in shared memory
    srandnum[lidx]  = curand_normal(&localState[lidx]);
    __syncthreads();

    if(lidx == 0){srandnum[lidx] += srandnum[lidx + 1];}   // sum of each block
    if(lidx == 0){gsum[blockIdx.x] = srandnum[lidx];}      // copy the sums back to global memory

    __threadfence();

    if( gidx < num_of_blocks){
        atomicAdd_d(&dev_sum, gsum[gidx]);
    }

    if( gidx < num_of_blocks){
        atomicMax_d(&dev_max, gsum[gidx]);
    }

    if( gidx == 0){
        printf("Sum is: %lf\n", dev_sum);
    }

    if( gidx == 1){
        printf("Max is: %lf\n", dev_max);
    }
}


int main(){
    // set seed on device
    curandState *globalState;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&globalState, tot_threads*sizeof(curandState));
    initcuRand<<<num_of_blocks, threads_per_block>>>(globalState, 1);

    // launch kernel
    kernel<<<num_of_blocks, threads_per_block>>>(globalState);
    double randnum[num_of_blocks];

    cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(randnum, gsum, num_of_blocks*sizeof(double), 0, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    std::cout << "Sum of each block:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_blocks; ++i){
        std::cout << randnum[i] << std::endl;
    }

    cudaFree(globalState);
    return 0;
}
```

The result I get is

```
Sum is: -0.898329
Max is: 0.000000
Sum of each block:
-0.0152994
-0.88303
```

From the result, I know that the `atomicAdd` function works but the `atomicMax` function doesn't work, I have no idea of this. Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't ever initialize `dev_max` or `dev_sum`.  You can't sensibly do these types of atomic operations on them if they don't start with a known value.

Try something like this instead:

```
__device__ double dev_sum = 0.0;

__device__ double dev_max = -1e99;
```

and I think you'll be happier with the results.

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks. But a quiz is that, if I do not initialise `dev_max`, the initial value of it should be very small and any of the block sum should be greater than that value, is it correct?

Comment: No.  In C or C++, if you don't initialize a variable, the initial value of it is undefined.  It could be anything.  Since these variables are floating point, that means the uninitialized value could even be `NaN`, which is completely useless for calculations.

Comment: Thanks again. But one more quiz if you don't mind. In my example, if I use `atomicAdd` function, it will compute the sum, can I copy the sum to the shared memory of each block and re-use it? My understanding is that the `dev_sum` is visible by all threads in the kernel function after atomic function, then if I use one thread on each block to copy to the shared memory but `__syncthreads()` before other operations by other threads in the same block, does it make sense to achieve some kind of synchronization between blocks?  As I known there is no function can guarantee block syn.

Comment: No, there is no way to synchronize between blocks.  You could copy `dev_sum` to shared memory, but there is no guarantee it would contain the final sum when you did so.  You could use an approach like the CUDA threadfence reduction sample code to get the final sum, but this would only be available to one block in your grid.